# Saml token Clock skew issue

Tags: saml, saml-2.0

We have a clock skew problem when issuing a SAML token to a client. The SSO server is ahead of time when compared to the requesting client.

**Time from my client** 
-bash-4.1$ date --utc 
Wed Sep 25 09:11:58 UTC 2013

**Time from sso server:** 
sh-3.2# date --utc 
Wed Sep 25 14:34:43 UTC 2013

Here is the error log

```
     The time now Wed Sep 25 14:25:01 UTC 2013 does not fall in the request lifetime interval extended with clock tolerance of 600000 ms:
[ Wed Sep 25 08:53:21 UTC 2013; Wed Sep 25 09:23:21 UTC 2013). This might be due to a clock skew problem.
```

How do we solve this?

Comment: What STS are you using?

Comment: We dont use any open source/free STS. I believe there is a customized STS that we talk to.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend trying to synchronize the time of the servers. If you configure the STS to tolerate a bigger skew you will counteract the purpose of that control.

Comment: I tried resetting my client's time and re-tried to get a saml token and it succeeded. But every time, there is a reboot of my machine, teh date is autopicked. Is there a way to reset the date for ever? 
If you have a better solution, let me kno

Comment: Have a look at time syncing with NTP